# How can I insert a value into a numpy record array?

Tags: python, numpy, record

This question has been edited as to make more sense.

The original question is how to insert values into a numpy record array, and I have had som success but still have an issue. Based off of the  website below I have been inserting values into a record array.

Python code

```
instance_format={
    'names' : ('name','offset'),
    'formats' : ('U100','U30')}

instance=np.zeros(20,dtype=instance_format)

#I am placing values in the array similar to this
instance[0]['name']="Wire 1"
instance[1]['name']="Wire 2"
instance[2]['name']="Wire 3"


instance[0]['offset']="0x103"
instance[1]['offset']="0x104"
instance[2]['offset']="0x105"

#Here is the insertion statement that works
instance1 = np.insert(instance1,1,"Module one")

print(instance1)
```

Output

```
[('One Wire 1', '0x103')
 ('Module One',  'Module One')
 ('One Wire 2', '0x104')
 ('One Wire 3', '0x105')
```

So the insert statement works, however it inserts it both in the name and the offset field. I want to insert it just in the name field. How do I this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `instance`

```
In [470]: instance
Out[470]: 
array([('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''),
       ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''),
       ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''),
       ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''),
       ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', ''), ('', '', '')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U100'), ('module', '<U100'), ('offset', '<U30')])
```

does not look like

```
 ['One Wire Instance 1', 'One Wire Instance 2', 'One Wire Instance 3']
```

Are you talking about one record of `instance`, which would display as

```
 ('One Wire Instance 1', 'One Wire Instance 2', 'One Wire Instance 3')
```

with each string being the `name`, `module`, and `offset`.

Or are these 3 strings e.g. `instance['name'][:3]`, the 'name' field from 3 records?

Inserting a new record into the `instance` array is one thing, adding a new field to the array is quite another.

---

To use `np.insert` with a structured array, you need provide a 1 element array with the correct dtype.

With your new `instance`:

```
In [580]: newone = np.array(("module one",'',''),dtype=instance.dtype)
In [581]: newone
Out[581]: 
array(('module one', '', ''), 
      dtype=[('name', '<U100'), ('module', '<U100'), ('offset', '<U30')])

In [582]: np.insert(instance,1,newone)
Out[582]: 
array([('Wire 1', '', '0x103'), ('module one', '', ''),
       ('Wire 2', '', '0x104'), ('Wire 3', '', '0x105')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U100'), ('module', '<U100'), ('offset', '<U30')])
```

`np.insert` is just a function that performs these steps:

```
In [588]: instance2 = np.zeros((4,),dtype=instance.dtype)
In [589]: instance2[:1]=instance[:1]
In [590]: instance2[2:]=instance[1:3]
In [591]: instance2
Out[591]: 
array([('Wire 1', '', '0x103'), ('', '', ''), ('Wire 2', '', '0x104'),
       ('Wire 3', '', '0x105')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U100'), ('module', '<U100'), ('offset', '<U30')])
In [592]: instance2[1]=newone
In [593]: instance2
Out[593]: 
array([('Wire 1', '', '0x103'), ('module one', '', ''),
       ('Wire 2', '', '0x104'), ('Wire 3', '', '0x105')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U100'), ('module', '<U100'), ('offset', '<U30')])
```

It creates a new array of the correct target size, copies elements from the original array, and puts the new array into the empty slot.

Comment: I added an example of how to use `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you mean by:

> I want to insert the name "Reserved" in the second element which would make the array have the following contents
>   ['One Wire Instance 1','Reserved' , 'One Wire Instance 2', 'One Wire Instance 3']

Do you want:

```
instance[1] = 'Reserved','', ''
```

?

Comment: Hi please check the edits, and since arrays are indexed at 0 it would be instance[1]= ' ','Reserved'